# Spring boot actuator CPU usage differs from Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, spring-boot-actuator

We have a spring boot app running inside a Docker container.  Spring boot Actuator reports 4-5% CPU usage, but cloudwatch reports 50-55%. Why is there a discrepancy? Are these stats measuring different things?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot inside the Docker container would give you a CPU usage of your container.

CloudWatch is reporting the CPU Utilization of your Instance. It is reported by the hypervisor and thus is quite accurate.